# ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule) while trying to load JSON data into table using *ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting the following error:

> ERROR NullInjectorError:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[DisplayLeaveRequestComponent ->
>   DisplayLeaveRequestService]:    StaticInjectorError(Platform:
>   core)[DisplayLeaveRequestComponent -> DisplayLeaveRequestService]

[image: Error Message]

display-leave-request.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { DisplayLeaveRequestService } from "./display-leave-request.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-display-leave-request",
  templateUrl: "./display-leave-request.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./display-leave-request.component.css"]
})
export class DisplayLeaveRequestComponent implements OnInit {
  public leaveRequestData = [];

  constructor(private _fetchedData: DisplayLeaveRequestService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._fetchedData
      .getLeaveRequests()
      .subscribe(data => (this.leaveRequestData = data));
  }
}
```

display-leave-request.service

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { ILeaveRequestData } from "./display-leave-request.interface";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class DisplayLeaveRequestService {
  private _URL = "../../assets/data/dataForTable.json";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getLeaveRequests(): Observable<ILeaveRequestData[]> {
    return this.http.get<ILeaveRequestData[]>(this._URL);
  }
}
```

display-leave-request.interface.ts

```
export interface ILeaveRequestData {
  leaveType: string;
  reasonForLeave: string;
  noOfDaysApplied: string;
  submittedOn: string;
  approvedOn: string;
  approvedBy: string;
}
```

app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { DisplayLeaveRequestComponent } from "./display-leave-request/display-leave-request.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, DisplayLeaveRequestComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add DisplayLeaveRequestComponent component to providers in app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
import { DisplayLeaveRequestComponent } from "./display-leave-request/display-leave-request.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, DisplayLeaveRequestComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [DisplayLeaveRequestService ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Thanks @Moslem_mh, the fix worked , but also I needed to add my service.ts file[DisplayLeaveRequestService] to the Providers like **providers: [DisplayLeaveRequestComponent, DisplayLeaveRequestService ]**, to work

Comment: friend I have a similar problem and I have not been able to fix it. could you help me?

Comment: Yes, no problem, if I can help you, what is you problem? @JulianProg